# Subquery - MySQL - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I have 2 tables.

table2 structure:

```
  name
  os
  count
```

table1 structure:

```
 name
```

Examples of table2:
       Fred    Android    50
       Tom     iOS         3
       Tom     iOS         3 
       Fred    Android     1
       Fred    Android     1
       James   iOS        20

Table1 has a list of names (unique).

My current query (stored in PHP variable $sqlx) is

```
$sqlx = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS numberOfRows FROM table2 where name = 'Fred' AND  count < '6' AND os = 'iOS' GROUP BY name";
```

How do I make a subquery so that I don't have to enter 'Fred' so that the name is selected from table1?

Comment: Did you mean for all the names in table 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the IN means you will check for all items in this list. Then using the second select query you are just pulling all names from table1. Here you can impose more conditions if you need to.

```
$sqlx = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS numberOfRows FROM table2 WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM table1) AND count < '6' AND os = 'iOS' GROUP BY name";
```